# Need to create a custom page on a website

Tags: pages, wp-admin, templates, code

I recently started my first wordpress task and it's about creating a custom page within a website. Now I know my PHP, CSS and HTML but while I am being used to working with angular etc. this is a new step for me.

I read about themes, plugins and templates but I do like to get some additional info from you all! Here are my questions:

- What should I use to create a page (with logic in it)? a theme, template or plugin?
- Is there a way to build up a page dynamically in wordpress? Like for example by a tag in the URL the pages show different images with the same tag?

The page im working with already has a standard theme so my new page should take over that style.

Thanks in advance!

wordpressNewb.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to build a custom page, the best place to look is the themes folder.

If your working on a custom made theme, you can add templates to the theme folder, and use them in your site. Otherwise, it's better to create a child theme for your customization ([Childthemes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)).

Within that new childtheme or existing custom theme, you start to add [page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). The page template is de base of your custom page. This is where all html and php magic happens ;-).

On [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) you can learn about the hierarchy of the wordpress theming system.